# running mvc website on azure emulator

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-roles

I am running a website locally in visual studio.
Azure sdk and emulator are installed.
for some reason its running under local iis , not with the azure emulator.

how can I get it to run with the emulator?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can do it by just **select your Azure role project as default project** like below.

**Step 1 :**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

I hope this will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cloud project, and not the mvc project, is the startup project. This should then run the site within the emulator.